# I want to display the last submitted message in conversation div without refreshing and reloading the page like whatsapp,facebook messenger and skype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

```
      <?php
     session_start();
     if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header("Location:login.php");
    }
     include 'connect.php';
     include 'functions.php';
     $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
     $hash = $_GET['hash'];
     if(isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
         $new_message = $_POST['message'];
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages`      VALUES('','$hash','$my_id','$new_message')");
         header('Location: startcon.php?hash='.$hash);
     }
 ?>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='css.css' />
 <script type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     function ()
     {
         $('#innerconversations').load('startcon.php').fadeIn("slow");
     }, 5000); // refresh every 5 seconds
 </script>
 <header>
     <div id="logo">
         <img src="logo.jpg" height="35px" width="35px">
     </div>
     <div id="options">
         <a href='profile.php'>Profile</a>&nbsp &nbsp 
         <a href="conversation.php">Messenger</a> &nbsp &nbsp 
         <a href="friends.php">Friends</a> &nbsp &nbsp  
         <a href="requests.php">Friend Requests</a> &nbsp &nbsp 
         <a href='find.php'>Find Friends</a> &nbsp &nbsp 
         <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a> &nbsp 
     </div>
 </header>  
 <div id='outerconversation'>
     <div id="conversationheader">
         <a href='conversation.php' title='back'>
             <img src='back.png' height='20px' width='18px' />
         </a>
     </div>
     <div id="innerconversations">
     <?php
         $message_query = mysql_query("SELECT from_id, message FROM      `messages` WHERE `group_hash`='$hash'");
         while($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)){
             $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
             $message = $run_message['message'];
             $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT `email`,`username` FROM      `users` WHERE id='$from_id'");
             $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
             $from_email = $run_user['email'];
             $from_username = $run_user['username'];
             echo "<hr color='#008298' /><span style='color: #008298; font-     family: Arial; margin-left: 10px;'>$from_username <span style='color: #BAB9B9;     font-style: italic;'>$from_email</span></span><br/><br/>";
             echo "<span style='color: #008298; font-family: Segoe UI Light;      margin-left: 30px;'><span style='color: #BAB9B9; font-family: Arial; margin-     left: 10px;'>says: </span>$message</span><br/><br/>";
         }
     ?>
     </div>
     <form method='POST'>
         <textarea name='message' placeholder="Type Message..."           maxlength="400" rows='6' cols='145'></textarea>
     </form>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var shiftDown = false;
 var chatForm = $("#chat_form");
 var messageBox = chatForm.children("textarea");

 $(document).keypress(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
         if(messageBox.is(":focus") && !shiftDown) {
             e.preventDefault(); // prevent another \n from being entered
             chatForm.submit();
         }
     }
  });

 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 16) shiftDown = true;
 });

 $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 16) shiftDown = false;
 });
 </script>
 </div>
```

I am working on chatting system but i have a problem that when i send message to another user he can't see the message until he refresh the page.I want like facebook messenger,whatsapp, skype that directly display message to reciever without refreshing or reloadin gthe page.I am very stuck and confused to what to do with it .I also add ready made refresh and update functions from this site(stackoverflow) and added into my website source code but i am getting an error that Undefined index: hash in C:\Xamp\htdocs\myfiles\startcon.php on line 9. What can i do please solve this issue. I am stuck and confused that what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax request to do this.
 I have done the same about a year ago and i have the code.
I don't write too much. I will upload it to dropbox and come back with the link for you.

Comment: Ok sure. I will be back as soon as i compressed the file and uploaded it to dropbox.

Comment: Thank You Ahmad bro. I will be waiting for you.

Comment: I am sorry for been silent two days. I was bosy developing some apps. But i created a project for you right today whoch will be simple to understand along with chat auto refresh. Here is the link to download it from dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0vs90fg8p0q5rw/samplechat.zip?dl=0 please let me know when you get this message. Thank you

Comment: Thank You So Much for your response Ahmad bro but my problem is so complicated and will solved only by myself. No one is able to solve this. It will solved only by myself. Thanks again

Comment: Ok. I thought you want to display messages between 2 opponents without page refreshing. That is why i did this for you because you will find this solution in it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is slightly different functionality to what a normal PHP application would provide.

When someone visits your page you need to set up a persistent "socket" connection to a server, so that new messages can be delivered between users.

Take a look at [Pusher](http://pusher.com), [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), or [Meteor](http://meteor.com). Doing this just with PHP you will find very hard.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry it would take you time to understand my code. It is complex php.
 But i found you an exact place for the right solution. Here is the demo, you can also download it.

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/06/chatting-with-jquery-and-ajax.html?m=1

All the best

Answer (score 0):

When a message comes in, perform an ajax request to select the users according to their id by desc limit, This would give you the result you want

Comment: Althoug you're right in that an Ajax call is a part of it, it is not the complete solution. In principle, you will need to post the message to the server backend from javascript, attaching a javascript callback function that will listen for the server response, and then update the client side page.

Comment: Yes.. push with socket, and when the message comes in, that's when the ajax should be performed, but speed is what should be watched out for.